# I was trying to shoot bullets from my current camera location but for some reason my bullets positions are wrong when camera moves

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glm-math

So I am trying to do a basic fps game for my project and I implemented a shooting animation. Bullets spawns from camera look vector(where player looks) and everything is fine when I just change camera look vector(when I look around with mouse). But when I change camera location (move around x and z coordinates) for some reason my bullets spawns left and right of the camera (for example if I go left bullets spawns a bit to the right). I tried various stuff but I couldn't solve the problem.

Here is how I create bullets.

```
for (int i = 0; i < BulletArray.size(); i++)
{

    if ( BulletArray[i].shooting_time + 4 >= currentFrame)
    {
        if (BulletArray[i].FirstFire)
        {

            BulletArray[i].BulletDirection = guy1.GetFrontLook();

            BulletArray[i].BulletPos = guy1.GetPos();

            BulletArray[i].FirstFire = false;
        }

        glm::mat4 BulletModel;
        BulletArray[i].BulletPos += BulletArray[i].BulletDirection*velocity;
        BulletModel = glm::translate(BulletModel, BulletArray[i].BulletPos);
        BulletModel = glm::scale(BulletModel, glm::vec3(0.01f));
        lightingShader.setMat4("model", BulletModel);
        lightingShader.setVec3("objectColor", 0.2f, 1.7f, 2.31f);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
    }
    else if (BulletArray[i].shooting_time + 4 < currentFrame)
    {
        BulletArray.erase(BulletArray.begin() + i);
    }

}
```

Here is how I update camera front vectors:

```
void update()
{
    glm::vec3 front;
    front.x = cos(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
    front.y = FrontGo.y;
    front.z = sin(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
    FrontGo = glm::normalize(front);
    if (prewYaw > Yaw)
    {
        lastRotationDegree = glm::acos(glm::dot(FrontGo, PrevFrontGo) / (glm::length(FrontGo) + glm::length(PrevFrontGo)));
    }
    else
    {
        lastRotationDegree = -glm::acos(glm::dot(FrontGo, PrevFrontGo) / (glm::length(FrontGo) + glm::length(PrevFrontGo)));
    }
    PrevFrontGo = FrontGo;
    prewYaw = Yaw;
    glm::vec3 frontl;
    frontl.x = cos(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
    frontl.y = sin(glm::radians(Pitch));
    frontl.z = sin(glm::radians(Yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(Pitch));
    FrontLook =  glm::normalize(frontl);
    Right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(FrontLook, wUp));
    Up = glm::normalize(glm::cross(Right,FrontLook));
}
```

Here is how I update camera position:

```
void ProcessKeyboardP(Player_Movement direction, float deltaTime)
{
    float velocity = MovementSpeed * deltaTime;
    if (direction == FORWARD_P)
        Position +=  FrontGo * velocity;
    if (direction == BACKWARD_P)
        Position -= FrontGo * velocity;
    if (direction == LEFT_P)
        Position -= Right * velocity;
    if (direction == RIGHT_P)
        Position += Right * velocity;

}
```

Comment: can you show `guy1.getPos()` implementation?

Comment: `if (BulletArray[i].FirstFire)` does this only activate the first time ever shooting or at the start of a burst and then reset?

Comment: @bruglesco yes it only activates first time. `BulletArray[i]` contains a struct  and First fire is true in default constructor. And  `getPos()` only returns `Position` variable and initial value of variable is `vec3(0,0,0)`.

Comment: is it an object pool where you reuse the bullets or are new bullets constructed every time you fire?

Comment: @bruglesco every time a new bullet is going to be shoot, it is constructed from scratch.

Comment: If getPos() always returns a `vec3(0,0,0)` why not just set it to that? If the bullets are always beginning at the origin point are you translating the mateix they use when you translate the matrix for the camera view?

Comment: @bruglesco it is initial value of Position it changes when camera moves.